# ListView GridViewColumnHeader with attached property and custom template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, attached-properties

I'm trying to customize a `ListView`'s `GridViewColumnHeader` on a column-by-column basis. I've been able to do this by manually setting each columns' `GridViewColumnHeader` as inline XAML (see the "Thing 2" column), which is OK but super repetitive, but I'd really rather have a reusable style with a control template with some attached properties (attempts are in the "Thing 1" column).

Basically, I need to style a unit of measurement text block, as well as a footer marker text block.

The attached properties appear to be set, but I haven't been able to figure out how to pull their values out in the template.

I realize that the `GridColumnHeader` isn't part of the visual tree, and that's likely the main hang-up here, but it seems so close!

The "Thing 1" column has the style set as inline XAML until I figure out how to get the attached property values. Ideally, it would be set in the control template like `ExampleListViewHeader`.

I've stripped out all the irrelevant code:

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="ExampleItems" Type="{x:Type local:ExampleItems}">
            <local:ExampleItems Cell1="Item 1-1" Cell2="Item 1-2" Cell3="Item 1-3" />
            <local:ExampleItems Cell1="Item 2-1" Cell2="Item 2-2" Cell3="Item 2-3" />
            <local:ExampleItems Cell1="Item 3-1" Cell2="Item 3-2" Cell3="Item 3-3" />
            <local:ExampleItems Cell1="Item 4-1" Cell2="Item 4-2" Cell3="Item 4-3" />
        </x:Array>

        <Style x:Key="ExampleListView" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 5" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ExampleListViewHeader" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Padding="2, 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource PLC_Font}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource PLC_FontSize_Sub_1}" />
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource ExampleItems}" Style="{StaticResource ExampleListView}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="100"
                                        local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker="1"
                                        local:HeaderAttachedProperties.UofM=" (ft) "
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cell1}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Thing 1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text=" (ft) " FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                                    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker}"/>-->

                                    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker)}"/>-->
                                    
                                    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}}, Path=(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker)}"/>-->
                                    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridViewColumn}, Path=(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker)}"/>-->
                                    
                                </Grid>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Width="100"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cell2}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Thing 2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text=" (ft) " FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="*" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Thing 3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cell3}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ExampleListViewHeader}" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

ExampleItems

```cs
public class ExampleItems
{
    public string Cell1 { get; set; }
    public string Cell2 { get; set; }
    public string Cell3 { get; set; }
}
```

HeaderAttachedProperties

```cs
public class HeaderAttachedProperties : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        name: "Marker",
        propertyType: typeof(string),
        ownerType: typeof(HeaderAttachedProperties),
        defaultMetadata: new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public static string GetMarker(DependencyObject pDependencyObject)
    {
        return (string)pDependencyObject.GetValue(MarkerProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMarker(DependencyObject pDependencyObject, string pValue)
    {
        pDependencyObject.SetValue(MarkerProperty, pValue);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UofMProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        name: "UofM",
        propertyType: typeof(string),
        ownerType: typeof(HeaderAttachedProperties),
        defaultMetadata: new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public static string GetUofM(DependencyObject pDependencyObject)
    {
        return (string)pDependencyObject.GetValue(UofMProperty);
    }

    public static void SetUofM(DependencyObject pDependencyObject, string pValue)
    {
        pDependencyObject.SetValue(UofMProperty, pValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need a `ControlTemplate`. You can use a `DataTemplate` instead. In order to bind the attached properties on `GridViewColumn`, you can use the `Column` property of `GridViewColumnHeader`.

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource PLC_Font}" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource PLC_FontSize_Sub_1}" />
   <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100"
                local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker="1"
                local:HeaderAttachedProperties.UofM=" (ft) "
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cell1}"
                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
   <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Thing 1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Column.(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.UofM), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}}" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Column.(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}}"/>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

If you parameterize the first `TextBlock`, too, you could extract and reuse it.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewHeaderTemplate">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Column.(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Anything), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}}" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Column.(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.UofM), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}}" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Column.(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}}"/>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100"
                local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker="1"
                local:HeaderAttachedProperties.UofM=" (ft) "
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cell1}"
                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderTemplate}"
                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
</GridViewColumn>
```

You can of course change the `ControlTemplate` instead, but you should be careful, because the it defines the visual appearance and states of the control. In your current template, you lose most of the states.

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewHeader" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Column.(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Anything), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Column.(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.UofM), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Column.(local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource PLC_Font}" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource PLC_FontSize_Sub_1}" />
   <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100"
                local:HeaderAttachedProperties.Marker="1"
                local:HeaderAttachedProperties.UofM=" (ft) "
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Cell1}">
   <GridViewColumnHeader Style="{StaticResource ListViewHeader}"/>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I omitted the `TextWrapping` and `VerticalAlignment` properties, reintroduce them where intended.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for taking the time to detail that all out- I really appreciate it.

Comment: Now that I've had a chance to get back to this item, yes, the goal was always to include the first item in that as well, I just figured if I couldn't make it work for the one field I was trying, no reason to change the code on three fields over and over.